# How to add a new column with values based on numeric value condition in R?

Tags: r, subset, cbind

I have a data frame with a colmn called concentration with numeric values.

```
Concentration
700657  
850789  
900123  
1011234  
750001
```

I want to add a new column CDrange that has values 700k+,800k+,900k+,1000k+. The values in the  new column will be assigned based on the value of concentration, e.g. if value is 700657, the calculated value should be 700k+, if value is 850789 then value as 800k+ and so on. How do I write a function without using if else loops. The new column should look like

```
Concentration       CDrange          
700657              700k+ 
850789              800k+ 
900123              900k+ 
1011234             1000k+ 
750001              700k+
```

Please provide on some suggestions on how to proceed. I have tried using subset function but I am unable to keep the dataframe together.

Comment: You didn't identify a language. I'm inferring R based on the **cbind** tag, so I submitted an edit to add the **r** tag. If this is incorrect, please edit your post to specify the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `?cut` and `?findInterval`.

```
df$CDrange <- cut(df$Concentration, c(700000, 800000, 900000, 1000000, Inf),
                  labels=c("700k+","800k+","900k+","1000k+") right=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this example:

```
x <- c(800000, 800001, 800999, 1234567)
paste0(x %/% 1000, ifelse((x %% 1000)>0, "k+", "k"))

#[1] "800k"   "800k+"  "800k+"  "1234k+"
```